# Add Batch File to Local Group Policy Editor

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, policy, group-policy, local-security-policy

I need write script using batch file to add **Local Group Policy Editor\Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)**

I'm trying to copy only to %%windir%%\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown but still no luck untill now. When I check in Local Computer, it still does not exist.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You only use one set of percent symbols to reference a variable.

Comment: Without a domain to push down policies, your other option is to edit the registry.  You can do that with reg.exe.   You will be adding to this key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Shutdown

Comment: @Squashman, wouldn't that just get deleted the next time group policy updates?

Comment: Hi @Squashman how to add files to the registry ? in my registry, there is no shutdown and startup scripts folder.